# How to retrieve virtual machines from a pool via API in oVirt (RHEV)

Tags: virtualization, redhat, rhev

In oVirt (Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization) you can create a Virtual Machines Pool to allow your users to retrieve virtual machines from this pool.

I found how a user, in the RHEV User Portal, can request a Virtual Machine from the pool, this is explained [here](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization/3.0/html/Evaluation_Guide/Evaluation_Guide-Allocate_VM.html)

The thing is that i will need to retrieve virtual machines from the pool with the REST API and, after reading the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization/3.0/html-single/REST_API_Guide/index.html) I can't found the way to do this.

Comment: pls see update to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such an API call, however, since the system is under very fast development, you as a customer can submit an RFE through a support ticket, those are usually satisfied with the next version, if they make sense and don't require very heavy changes

UPDATE: In RHEV 3.1 there is an API action called `allocatevm`:

```
<vmpools>
  <vmpool href="/api/vmpools/cfc75028-2942-11e2-8f69-52540042e41d" id="cfc75028-2942-11e2-8f69-52540042e41d">
  <actions>
    <link href="/api/vmpools/cfc75028-2942-11e2-8f69-52540042e41d/allocatevm" rel="allocatevm"/>
  </actions>
...
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using oVirt 3.1 (3.1.0-2.fc17) and there is no such call, or at least is not visible When I request the vmpools using the API (as it seems in your example).

Comment: It could have been backported from oVirt 3.2 into RHEV 3.1

Comment: I found the patch for this feature (http://gerrit.ovirt.org/gitweb?p=ovirt-engine.git;a=commitdiff;h=960ff6d1d70126dacb9f12991fd23fb9a2a50a0f) and the bug report (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=864438) but I can't find a way to know in what version this will be fixed.

Comment: what you found is a RHEV bug, and it's closed as fixed - the feature exists in the current version of RHEV

Comment: Can you please tell me the detailed number of version of RHEV are you using?

Comment: the latest one available from RHN. I don't use oVirt on a daily basis, just for some tests sometimes